# No Persistent State On Refresh With History.js

Tags: php, jquery, history.js

I implemented History.js on my page recently, and am having an issue with the script.  If I go to the index page, and click a link things work just like they should.  New content gets loaded, no page refresh, and all nav links still work.  However, if I refresh after using one of the links, then click a link, the URL changes but none of the content does.  I'm not sure what's going on.

Back and forward buttons work fine, and I can access the navigation after using them.  Here's the javascript I'm using:

```
function fire()
{
var
History = window.History,
State = History.getState();

$('a').live('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var path = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    History.pushState('ajax',title,path);
}
);

// Bind to state change
// When the statechange happens, load the appropriate url via ajax
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() 
    { 
        load_ajax_data();
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
    }
);

function load_ajax_data() {
 State = History.getState();   
 $.post(State.url, function(data) {
 $("#content").load(State.url + ' #contentDiv'); 
    }); 
 }
}

$(document).ready(fire());
```

Comment: The documentation for History.js says that it solves the browser issue of "State data and titles do not persist once the site is left and then returned (includes page refreshes)" which should mean that I can use the nav links, refresh the page, and the navigation should all still work.  I'm not sure why it doesn't.  I'll update my question with the code I'm using in my javascript file.

Comment: **This has not been fixed**, so if anyone has any ideas, please share!

Comment: did you managed to find any solution with refresh issue as same is happening with my demo app with history.js. Please reply back. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but I had the same problem, after refreshing the page the navigation was not working but you can saw the url chaining.

To fixed just update to the latest version of History.js https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

This is my code:

```
//Under Document.ready
if (History.enabled) {
      var History = window.History;
          History.Adapter.bind(window, "popstate", function() {
                    var State = History.getState();
                    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);

                    if (JSON.stringify(State.data) != "{}") {
                        var obj = State.data.content;
                        search = State.data.search;
                        $("#content").html(obj);
                        $("#search").val(search);
                    }
          });
    }
```

And because I only want to push the state on ajax request:

```
//under .ajaxStop
 History = window.History;
            if (History.enabled) {
                var grid = $("#content").html();
                var search = $("#search").val();
                History.pushState({ content: grid, search: search }, "Search", "?" + $("#FormID").serialize());
            }
```

Where **#content** is the div where my partial view is rendered and **#search** is a textbox element.

**Note: I was using Histyori.js 1.7 and after updating to 1.8 everything start working.**

I hope this can be useful for some one else.